# Specify html content in html and have React process this

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to have this markup in the html:

```
<tabs>
    <tab title="a title" tab-content="content">
    <tab title="a title" tab-content="content">
</tabs>
```

and have react take that structure and create tabs functionality from it? i.e. create a list from the tab titles and divs for the content which get switched on/off depending on which tab is active.

I've come a background in Angular so may be thinking too angular-centric.

Comment: Yes it is possible, where <Tabs /> would be a react component. Which creates <TabTitle /> components :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to go about creating tabbed content in React. What I believe you're asking though - specifying the content in the html - seems counter to the "react way" of doing things. From the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html):

> Remember: React is all about one-way data flow down the component
>   hierarchy. It may not be immediately clear which component should own
>   what state. This is often the most challenging part for newcomers to
>   understand...

The data for a given component is passed to the DOM rather than derived from it. So I wouldn't expect a React navigation component to get its functionality from existing html content but from the `props` passed in from the parent component or `state` that it manages itself.

While you could build this yourself, you may want to look at [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) which will provide some mechanisms for client-side routing and managing tabbed content.

Comment: Thanks, I thought this were the case. I'm wondering then, if the content in my tabs were user-generated how would i get this in to the jsx...with difficulty I imagine.

Comment: Depends on where the UGC is coming from (a form on the page, AJAX), but that data would be passed into your tabs from "outside" the component. A quick-and-dirty approach would be to fire an AJAX request in the component's `componentDidMount` hook and then call `this.setState` with the data on success. Beyond that, look at a [Flux architecture](http://pixelhunter.me/post/110248593059/flux-solutions-compared-by-example) for managing the data.